# Can I use a swift dictionary in a subclass of AWSDynamoDBModel?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a class that inherits from AWSDynamoDBModel and adheres to AWSDynamoDBModeling protocol. Example:

```
class ProfileDatabaseModel : AWSDynamoDBModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {
    var userid: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var someOtherStuff: [String: String] // IS THIS OK?

    // assume some other details here, like initializations

    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! {
        return "atable"
    }

    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! {
        return "userid"
    }
}
```

With a class like this, I can perform the following few lines that update the DynamoDB with the data in an instantiation of this class:

```
var db = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()
var model = ProfileDatabaseModel()
// fill in model data
let task: BFTask = db.save(model)
```

My question is: Can I have that dictionary in the object? Will that work with the object mapper? If not as a Swift dictionary, would it work as an NSDictionary? Or, do I need to translate it to a JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper` supports:

1. `NSNumber`
2. `NSString`
3. `NSData`
4. `NSArray` of the above three datatypes

`NSDictionary` is not supported, but we are evaluating how we can support the map datatype in the coming releases.

Comment: 2.0.16 - Added support for new data types: BOOL, List, and Map


https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2016